# How do I put a dict inside a dict of dicts?

Tags: python

So I have a dict that I wanna place inside a dict of dicts and I just can't figure out how. So this is my code:

```
        song_info = get_info(song)

        queues[server] = [song]

        queues[server][song] = [song_info]
```

Ok so the function `get_info` returns a dict with all the info from the song, so what I want to do is put that info on a dict with the `song` as the name of the dict and put that dict inside a dict with the name of the server which is inside of a bigger dict called queues that has all dicts of all serves. I know it is a bit hard to follow but if someone could help me I would really apreciate it!

and by the way when I try running this code it gives me this error

```
list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

so the final product needs to look something like this:

```
queues = {'server1' : ['song1' : {'title' : 'song title', 'duration' : 'song_duration', etc}, 'song2' : {'title' : 'song title', 'duration' : 'song_duration', etc}], 'server2' : ['song3' : {'title' : 'song title', 'duration' : 'song_duration', etc}, 'song4' : {'title' : 'song title', 'duration' : 'song_duration', etc}] }
```

`song_info = {'title' : 'song title', 'duration' : 'song_duration', etc}`

`song = is just the songs name`

`server = an int`

Comment: Please provide example data that shows what `song` and `server` look like, as well as what the expected return value from `get_info` looks like (so what `song_info` looks like) - with those examples, please show what you expect `queues` to look like after your code runs. As you assign `[song]` to `queues[server]`, this is now a list, and apparently `song` itself is a string, causing the error on the final line.

Comment: Please post a [MCVE]

Comment: I've edited, is it clearer now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dicts are declared with curly braces, and each value must have an associated key.  When you say:

```
queues[server] = [song]
```

you're creating a *list*, not a *dict*, which is why you're getting an error when you subsequently try to assign a value to it as if it were a dict.

Try:

```
song_info = get_info(song)

queues = {}
queues[server] = {}
queues[server][song] = song_info
```

Or easier yet, use `defaultdict` so you don't need to create an empty dict for each `server` key:

```
from collections import defaultdict

queues = defaultdict(dict)
queues[server][song] = get_info(song)
```